# Sending AJAX for each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, jsp

Let say I create a list like:

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
  <p>${user.id} ${user.name}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Now I want to add a delete button (link or submit) that does:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "DELETE",
  url: "../delete" + ID,
  ...
});
```

with the ID of that row.

How to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Where in the markup, would you add the delete button?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
  <p>${user.id} ${user.name}</p>
  <button class="delete-user" data-user="${user.id}">Delete</button>
</c:forEach>
```

In your code jquery you can retrieve userID like this:

```
$('.delete-user').click(function(){
    var userId = $(this).data( "user" );
    // You code here
})
```